# Convert Minutes in HH:MM in SQL-Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I get the result bellow:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DateAdd(MINUTE, 8400, '00:00:00'),108)
```

Like: `HH:MM`? In this case it should return `140:00`.

Thanks

Comment: can't, really. convert targets date/time formats, not "intervals". `hh` is a 0->23, and anything 24+ gets rolled over into days.

Comment: Yeah, i see. This was confusing me. But there isn't a way to get the output in total hours:minutes using minutes? Thanks for your time

Comment: sure, convert to seconds, and then do some basic math to build your own interval strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/` and `%` to get the hours and minutes. Use `replicate` in case the `%` returns a value of length `1`.

```
select cast(minutescol/60 as varchar(100)) + ':' + 
replicate('0', 2-len(minutescol%60)) + cast(minutescol%60 as varchar(100))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works! and congratulations for 10k rep. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare @Minutes int  = 398;
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18, 2), @Minutes / 60 + (@Minutes % 60) / 100.0),'.',':')
```

Output:

```
6:38
```